# AT+CUSD=1, *123#, 15 always returns an error

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem, huawei-developers

I'm using the old huawei 3g modem broadband stick. I can send message using the at+commands but i can't get its balance using the

```
AT+CUSD=1, "*123#, 15
```

It always returns error
I just need it for my thesis

I've tried different sim card with its corresponding USSD but it's still returns an error.

Comment: Is it **exactly** what you send? In that case, a closing quote is missing in `"*123#`. I would also remove spaces when sending commands. I suggest always enabling, in debug phase, verbose errors to AT commands with `AT+CMEE=2` (errors in text format) or `AT+CMEE=1` (errors in numeric format).